# How can I do a accent insensitive search in Postgres 8.3.x with a DB in utf-8?

Tags: postgresql, diacritics, case-sensitive

Tried select to_ascii('capo','LATIN1'), to_ascii('çapo','LATIN1') and the results are different....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](http://www.laudatio.com/wordpress/2008/11/05/postgresql-83-to_ascii-utf8).

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_ascii(bytea, name)
RETURNS text STRICT AS 'to_ascii_encname' LANGUAGE internal;
```

and then just use it like this:

```
SELECT to_ascii(convert_to('Übermeier', 'latin1'), 'latin1');
```