# It is possible to retrieve a value from a table without spanish characters?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's possible to retrieve a value (stored with spanish characters like 'ñ' or 'á') from any given table without spanish character? i.e:

If I have the value 'Japón' stored, retrive it like 'Japon'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.laudatio.com/wordpress/2008/11/05/postgresql-83-to_ascii-utf8/) may help (already mentioned as an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659076/how-can-i-do-a-accent-insensitive-search-in-postgres-8-3-x-with-a-db-in-utf-8)).